# Is there a better way to find associations on a class level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here are the objects I am working with:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :servers

  def self.active
    where("updated_at > ?", 1.month.ago)
  end
end

class Server
  belongs_to :client
end
```

I would like to be able to get all the servers that belong to active clients like so:

```
Client.active.servers
```

The only way I can think to do this is:

```
def Client.servers
  Server.where(id: all.collect(&:id))
end
```

There must be a more Rails-y to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've found what you're looking for, and it's the Active Record method [`merge`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge).

```
Server.joins(:client).merge(Client.active)
```

In testing, if you find a conflict with your `updated_at` column, be sure to disambiguate it in your `active` scope:

```
def self.active
  where("clients.updated_at > ?", 1.month.ago)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to join to the client from server. Something like this should work:

`Server.joins(:client).where('clients.updated_at > ?', 1.month.ago)`

Comment: But I want to be able to use the query methods defined on class Client. If I do it this way, I either violate DRY or encapsulation (by defining them on Server).

Comment: so violate them. they're just guidelines. this is how you query for servers based on an attribute in a join table. the alternative is some obtuse flat_map from clients to servers.